# Background image not resizing below 700px

Tags: html, css, background-image

I was handed an existing website to work on that is having responsive issues for a background image. The `#banner` that the background-image is assigned to is responsive above a breakpoint @700px, but won't resize below that screen width, breaking the responsiveness of the site below that breakpoint.

HTML:

```
<section id="banner">
<header>
<em><b>CALL 716-763-0069 Proudly Serving New York & Pennsylvania For Over 35 Years</b></em>
</header>               
</section>`
```

CSS:

```
background-image: url("../../images/IMG_1890.jpg");
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
height: 28em;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
```

It seems the background-image is scaled using height in ems across various breakpoints. Here's a few of the more relevant breakpoints for perspective:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 840px) {
#banner {height: 20em;}}

@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {
#banner {height: 18em;}}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
#banner {height: 16em;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of that website has a `min-width: 700px`. Take it out and the site will be responsive at any size.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank's for the perspective, I was so focused on the background image that I missed the min-width. Very Much appreciated, thank you!